# I wonder how identity provider connect to user store.There is no configuration when adding idp

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have already configured SSO with SAML. But I didn't add identity provider.How is user identity provided from user store, including primary and secondary user store, to service provider. Is it possible to assign a specific user store to a service provider? I need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure SAML SSO you don't have to add Identity Provider only Service Provider is enough. Currently there is no way to add specific user store to Service Provider but you can authenticate by using both PRIMARY or secondary user store.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you.
I think a identity provider is only available for federated authenticators, the external applications, such as yahoo, google. Right?